# How to create a column containing whitespace using assign() method in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

**Sample Data:**

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame({'Original City': {'Daimler': 'Chicago',
  'Mitsubishi': 'LA',
  'Tesla': 'Vienna',
  'Toyota': 'Zurich',
  'Renault': 'Sydney',
  'Ford': 'Toronto'}})

df2=pd.DataFrame({'Current City': {'Tesla': 'Amsterdam',
  'Renault': 'Paris',
  'BMW': 'Munich',
  'Fiat': 'Detroit',
  'Audi': 'Berlin',
  'Ferrari': 'Bruxelles'}})
```

**Now my question is:**

I am trying to create a column containing `whitespace` using `assign()` method:

```
df1.assign(Original City=df2['Current City'])
                   ^
               #white space
```

**I tried:**

```
df1.assign('Original City'=df2['Current City'])
df1.assign(r'Original City'=df2['Current City'])
```

And as expected It is giving me an error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-132-2ac564ac9d47>", line 1
    df1.assign(Original City=df2['Current City'])
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But I can able to assign my column like this:

```
df1.assign(OriginalCity=df2['Current City'])
```

**Is it possible to create a column containing ' ' space(white space) using `assign()` method?**

Comment: Having spaces in identifiers are not allowed. `dict(a=1)` works but `dict(a b=1)` doesnot

Comment: @anky Thanks for the information....I also thinked this but I was wondering that Is there a way for doing so **:)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use unpack dictionary:

```
d = {'Original City':df2['Current City']}
df1.assign(**d)
```

Or unpack a dataframe:

```
df1.assign(**df2[['Current City']].rename({'Current City': 'Original City'}))
```

Comment: Thanks @Quang Hoang....I was thinking to ask this question from many past days